# Truncated versus floored division in Python

Tags: python, division

To establish context, I'm talking about integer arithmetic only, on large integers so going via floating point isn't an option, and using negative numbers so the difference between floored and truncated division matters.

When performing division on negative integers, typical hardware and C family programming languages give the truncated result e.g. 1 / -2 = 0. Python 2 gives the floored result e.g. 1 / -2 = -1.

Notwithstanding arguments about which is intrinsically better, is there a way to get Python to give the truncated result? Does it make any difference if you use Python 3 instead of 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, if you just want a solution, remember `int` truncates the number, so instead of doing integer divison, truncate a float with `int`

```
int(1./-2)
```

If you are using Python 3.X, you can simply do

```
int(1/2)
```

If you want the same behavior in Py 2.X import division from future

```
from __future__ import division
int(1/2)
```

If you want to know the exact reason for this behavior, read this wonderful article [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html)

---

Looking at your predicament in using float for division, here is an alternate approach that seems to be working as far as I have tested. Feel free to let me know of any issues you are facing

```
>>> def trunc_div(a,b):
    q, r = divmod(a,b)
    if  q < 0 and r:
        q += 1
    return q

>>> trunc_div(1,-2)
0
>>> trunc_div(999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, -2)
-499999999999999999999999999999999999999999L
>>> trunc_div(999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 2)
499999999999999999999999999999999999999999L
>>> trunc_div(1,2)
0
>>>
```

Comment: Try `int(100000000000000000000000. / 2)`... (32-bit machine)

Comment: Again, I'm talking only about integer arithmetic, not about floating point. I understand the reasons why floor is intrinsically better, but as I said, that's a different question; what I'm looking for in this context is a way to emulate the behavior of typical hardware and programming languages.

Comment: @OmriBarel: Thank you for doing stress testing and due to you, I have an update. Kindly feel free to stress and stretch as much as your mind goes :-)

Comment: `divmod(-5,-2) = (2,-1)`, so `trunc_div(-5,-2) = 3`, which is wrong (should be 2).

Comment: @OmriBarel: Race condition, my fix and your comment :-). I was incorrectly testing the remainder instead of quotient

Comment: Yes, that seems to work for me (tried with large numbers, both positive and negative). I'll withdraw my answer which is longer and less elegant.

Comment: @OmriBarel: Instead of deleting your answer, why don;t you work on it to make it a `divmod` alternative? That will be more generic and useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 has new-style division (which can also be triggered in Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> -1 / 2
-0.5
>>> -1 // 2
-1
```

I don't think you can get truncated division, you'd probably have to use math.floor().

Comment: That's floored, not truncated. Again, I'm talking only about integer arithmetic, floating point isn't involved at all.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I got them mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this solves your problem, but it is a function call, not a simple operation:

```
def truncdiv(a, b):
    if a < 0:
        a = -a
        b = -b
    if b < 0:
        return (a + b + 1) / b
    return a / b
```

Answer (score 0):

The [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) library supports truncated division:

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.mpz(-100)//7
mpz(-15)
>>> gmpy2.t_div(gmpy2.mpz(-100),7)
mpz(-14)
>>>
```

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: Using a multi-precision integer (including any dependencies required) is overkill.