# python how to get truncated modulo vs floored modulo

Tags: python, modulo

I get Truncated versus floored division in Python can be used like this [Truncated versus floored division in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633787/truncated-versus-floored-division-in-python)

we use / vs //

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> -1 / 2
-0.5
>>> -1 // 2
-1
```

but is there an equivalent for modulo?

like when the dividend is negative

for
−9 mod 4. Clearly, we have

−9 = 4 * (−2) − 1

and

−9 = 4 * (−3) + 3.

the floored modulo implies that −9 mod 4 = 3

the truncated modulo implies that −9 mod 4 = −1

for python modulo operator, it is using % floored version as default
-61 % 60 = 59

is there built in/library support similar to truncated versus floored division for modulo or I need to use my own?

this is about truncated vs floored modulo not about division

reference [https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/modulo-of-negative-numbers#:~:text=remainder%20are%20negative.-,When%20both%20the%20divisor%20and%20dividend%20are%20negative,division%20return%20the%20negative%20remainder](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/modulo-of-negative-numbers#:%7E:text=remainder%20are%20negative.-,When%20both%20the%20divisor%20and%20dividend%20are%20negative,division%20return%20the%20negative%20remainder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon some research the default modulo method is language dependent, for python

```
8 % -3 = -1
```

for javascript for example

```
8 % -3 = 2
```

it is because for js it uses the trunc method

```
r = a - (n * trunc(a/n))
r is the remainder.
a is the dividend.
n is the divisor.
```

for python it is the floor method

```
r = a - (n * floor(a/n))
```

however there is no simple way to switch in python like we do with floor and trunc division to use / vs //
but there is a math library function we could use

```
>>> 8.0 % -3
-1.0

>>> import math
>>> math.fmod(8.0, -3.0)
2.0
```

worth noting not all modulo operations in Python are the same. While the modulo used with the int and float types will take the sign of the divisor, other types will not.

reference https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/#modulo-operator-with-a-negative-operand

Answer (score 2):

There is [`math.remainder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.remainder):

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.remainder(-9, 4)
-1.0
>>> int(math.remainder(-9, 4))
-1
>>> -9 % 4
3
```